# Is it possible to create a string of alphabet characters (seperated by ands) based on the number of members of a global variable in SAS?

Tags: string, merge, sas, global

I am looking to build a system that merges data sets based on common values using the merge function.

However I know that sometimes I will have to merge 2 data sets, and sometimes I will have to merge 20 data sets.

so the generic merge function looks as follows

```
DATA [data_set];
    merge
     [loop over data to be merged]
    by [factors which I am merging by]
    if [a and b]
    format [sort order]
run;
```

The problem is that after the if the [a and b] obviously needs to be a string generated to be the length equal to the number of tables being merged. If I want to merge 2 tables [a and b] is great but if I want to merge 3 tables it would have to be [a and b and c].

Is there a way for me to generate a string [a and b and.... N] where is produced based on the length of a global variable?

Hopefully my question is clear, I cannot provide the actual code I am using as it contains sensitive information. I will try to provide more information / answer questions as best I can if there is something I missed.

Using the makedata function from @Richard

```
%let MergeData = X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10;
DATA X_COMB;
        merge 
            %internalmacro1(
                %nrstr(
                        #L1#;
                        )
            ,L1 = &MergeData.
            );  
        by id;
        if ; /* create a string based on %&MergeData length, of # and # and # ... where # = a,b,c,d */                      
run;
```

but where that last if exists I want the number of items in the %MergeData set, I think I need to make an array and convert to hex for the values maybe? There must be some equivalent hex value for 'a b c' etc.

The problem is that people are going to add and remove items to the set &MergeData so the merge I'm trying to create needs to scale to the size of the number of data sets being input? Sorry I can't provide more!

**Rosie Method:**

```
proc import 
    datafile = "FilePath\Alphabet.csv"
    DBMS = csv 
    OUT = AlphabetConversion;
;



 data desiredstatements;
    set AlphabetConversion (obs=26); /*This limits the observations used*/
run;

proc sql;
    select AlphabetConversion into :dynamiccode from desiredstatements separated by " and ";
quit;
%put &dynamiccode.; /*Check the log to see what you got and make sure it's the code you want */
```

**Quentin Method:**

```
DATA Merged_Data
merge 
mydata1 (in=_mydata1) mydata2(in=_mydata2) mydata3 (in=_mydata3);
by ID;
if _mydata1 and _mydata2 and _mydata3;
```

This structure is fine for a merge where you get to specify all of your inputs. My problem is that I am trying to write a macro that will take mydata1 and mydata2 sometimes, and mydata1-mydata20 other times. I don't know how to make the if _mydata1 and _mydata2 .... _mydata20, when it has 20 data sets to be merged, and _mydata1 and _mydata2 when it only has two.

Comment: Are you writing a macro to do this in a generic way? If so, please post the macro code you've written so far, or at least a minimal version of it with any sensitive information removed.

Comment: I am intending to write a macro, but I'm not really sure where I'm supposed to start. I'm pretty new to SAS. I will post updates as I make progress, I wondered if people had encountered this problem before.

Comment: Do you know how to use the data set option `(in=flag-var)`?  Are `a` and `b` satellite variables in the being merged tables, or are they supposed to be flag variables that a row from a particular table is being processed, as based on the by variables (i.e. a table is participating in the by group)

Comment: You may be trying to learn macros too soon. It’s better to first learn DATA step code really well. That said, I suggest you show an example of the data step code you want, showing how you would merge 3 datasets. It sounds like `merge mydata1 (in=_mydata1) mydata2(in=_mydata2) mydata3 (in=_mydata3); by ID; if _mydata1 and _mydata2 and _mydata3;`  If you look into macro looping, should be straight forward to write a macro that accepts a list of datasets as a parameter and generates that code. Note in this case using in=_mydata or just in=_&i should simplify things, rather than generating in=_a.

Comment: @Quentin tried to better explain my problem in the main post. I understand how to merge when I can manually merge them, it's because I need a data step which will merge based on any number of merges required. (up to 20 only)

Comment: Understood. You can use the macro language to generate SAS code. In this case a macro cold generate the list datasets on the merge statement and a list for the IF statement. If you don’t have a workable answer in the next couple days, I should be back to having SAS access and will post an example. In the mean time, google macro looping.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question, does the following achieve what you want?:

```
%let ds_list   = a b c d;
%let ds_and_ds = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&ds_list,%str( ),%str( and )));

%put ds_list   = &ds_list;
%put ds_and_ds = &ds_and_ds;
```

If not, then please give an example of the data set list into which you want to insert "and" between each data set.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can some example code, based on this data

```
%macro makedata;

  %local i;

  data %do i = 1 %to 10; x&i(keep=id x&i)  %end;;
    do id = 1 to 42;
      array x(10);
      do _n_ = 1 to dim(x);
        x(_n_) = id * 100 + _n_;
      end;
      output;
    end;
  run
%mend;

%makedata;

data want;
  merge ... fill in the rest ...;
  ... fill in the rest ...
run;
```

Comment: Tried to update the main post to more clearly explain my goal using this? Still no idea how to make the string I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You're close with your attempt of the code I gave you earlier, but the one key thing (other than me giving you the wrong order for the SQL statement - sorry about that, fixed below) is that you are reading in a CSV and assuming it has headers, whereas I would prefer to define the variable in the code. And then you are naming the dataset name when you should be naming the variable in the `proc SQL` - try this:

```
/*File must have one letter pet row*/
%let file=\\hefce-sas\nuser\user\thomaro\SAS\Temp\Alphabet.csv;

data AlphabetConversion;
    infile "&file."
    delimiter=',' missover dsd;
    format letter $1.;
    input letter $;
run;

/*I've explicitly defined this so it runs but this needs to be dynamic - see below*/
%let numstatements = 5; 

 data desiredstatements;
    set AlphabetConversion (obs=&numstatements.); /*This limits the observations used*/
run;

proc sql;
    select letter into :dynamiccode separated by ' and ' from desiredstatements;
quit;
/*Check the log to see what you got and make sure it's the code you want */
%put &dynamiccode.;
```

This construct is very useful in general for dynamically creating code.

Now there is the question of dynamically defining `numstatements` - this should be based on the line at the top of your code:

```
%let MergeData = X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10;
```

So I would suggest you want a macro function that counts words - there isn't one of these, but you can turn the normal function `countw` into a macro function using `%sysfunc()` - so you would want to replace the `%let` above with something like this:

```
%let numstatements = %sysfunc(countw(&mergedata.));
%put The number of datasets to be merged is &numstatements.;
```

Now (if I've understood your problem correctly) when you want to run the code with a different number of datasets, all you need to do is change your `%let MergeData=` at the top of the code and you're good to go.

Comment: Hi Rosie, would you be able to show an example of this?

Suppose I have 3 data sets %let SampleSet = X1 X2 X3

How would I make &dynamiccode. produce "a and b and c"? I feel like I'm missing a step.

Comment: Are 'a and b' actually your conditions? I have indeed missed out the first step (intentionally, but because I don't know what you want to do), I was assuming your conditions were more complicated - you would have to pre-write them into a dataset, but you could then call upon 'the top 3' or 'the top 15' dynamically. I think it is difficult to see what you are trying to do without an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: Oh I see what you are trying to do with Richard's code now - but, I think if you just enter the characters a through z into a dataset (one row per character) and keep it somewhere, you should be able to use the code above? Might not be the simplest method overall, though. Do you also need a way to get the variable `&numstatements.` or is that provided/trivial?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding. But in order to merge two tables does it not require [if a and b], and to merge three tables does it not require [if a and b and c]? That is why I wish to generate the strings, and sometimes I need to merge 5 datasets, and sometimes I need to merge 10 datasets. I don't want to manually type the rest of the letters each time.

Comment: Depends on the type of merge, but assuming you only want the observations that are common across all the datasets, then yes. But what I'm suggesting is just making a one-time data set, which you store (but not necessary to store), which contains the maximum possible number of letters you will ever require, one per row. Then the code above will generate the dynamic 'if a and b ...' statement, assuming you are able to easily count the number of input datasets (if you are not, let me know and I can generate that based on your `%let` statement).

Comment: I have tried your method as suggested, included in the main post. My log is only telling me WARNING: Macro variable "&dynamiccode" was not resolved though. Probably now I've made the csv then I can ignore your first data step?

Comment: The main issue was that you were referring to the dataset name in the part of the SQL code where you should've had the variable name (plus I wrote the SQL code the wrong way round, sorry). I've put a more full answer above now. let me know if there is anything else in the code that needs to be dynamically generated - I wasn't quite sure which bits you were missing.

Answer (score 0):

Given a bunch of data sets like:

```
data mydata1 ;
  input id x1 ;
  cards ;
1 10
2 20
3 30
;

data mydata2 ;
  input id x2 ;
  cards ;
1 100
3 300
;

data mydata3 ;
  input id x3 ;
  cards ;
1 1000
2 2000
3 3000
;
```

You can merge them together and keep only the records that match between all three data sets like:

```
data all ;
  merge 
    mydata1 (in=_mydata1) 
    mydata2 (in=_mydata2)
    mydata3 (in=_mydata3)
   ;
  by id ;
  if _mydata1 and _mydata2 and _mydata3 ;
run ;
```

If you look at the above step, it's clear that there are two lists.  A list of data sets on the merge statement, and a list of variables on the IF statement.  You can use the macro language to generate that step.  When you call the macro you would pass it a list of data sets to be merged. The macro would then generate the DATA step with the merge.

Here's a macro, which uses macro looping to generate the two lists:

```
%macro innermerge 
  (data= /*space-delimited list of data sets to be merged*/
  ,by= /*space-delimited list of BY variables for merge*/
  ,out= /*output data set*/
  )
;

%local i data_i ;

data &out ;
  merge
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&data,%str( ))) ;
      %let data_i=%scan(&data,&i,%str( )) ;

      &data_i (in=_&data_i)

    %end ;
  ;

  by &by ;

  if
    %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&data,%str( ))) ;
      %let data_i=%scan(&data,&i,%str( )) ;

      %if &i>1 %then %do ;
        and
      %end ;

      _&data_i 


    %end ;
  ;
  run ;

%mend;
```

Use like:

```
%innermerge
  (data=mydata1 mydata2
  ,by=id
  ,out=want
  )
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   data want ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   merge mydata1 (in=_mydata1) mydata2 (in=_mydata2) ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   by id ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   if _mydata1 and _mydata2 ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   run ;

NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.MYDATA1.
NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK.MYDATA2.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 2 observations and 3 variables.


%innermerge
  (data=mydata1 mydata2 mydata3
  ,by=id
  ,out=want
  )
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   data want ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   merge mydata1 (in=_mydata1) mydata2 (in=_mydata2) mydata3 (in=_mydata3) ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   by id ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   if _mydata1 and _mydata2 and _mydata3 ;
MPRINT(INNERMERGE):   run ;

NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.MYDATA1.
NOTE: There were 2 observations read from the data set WORK.MYDATA2.
NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.MYDATA3.
NOTE: The data set WORK.WANT has 2 observations and 4 variables.
```